# Main objectives of java Runtime Exception and why they occur as well as the best practices for evasion of java runtime exception

Tags: java, netbeans, runtimeexception

Hello fellow pragmatic programmers, I have this program which I developed which is a social network program written in java and the main functions of this program is to allow the user to: add a friend, delete friend, see who has the most friends, see who has the most high influence and the ability to exit out of the program.

As with any programs there will be a blip or two, for me it is a case of the java runtime exception this keeps of propping up after I tried to remedy the problem by seeing if it will work without the main package or if I tried to change the way I have written the program to no avail.

This is the error message that keeps on propping up:

```
Select:
[1] Add Friend
[2] Delete Friend
[3] List Friends
[4] Friends of Friends
[5] Most Popular
[6] Most Influencer
[7] Exit
7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: uelbook.Person
    at uelbook.UELbook.main(UELbook.java:20)
```

Line 20 of my main class which is UELbook which is down below is:

```
 Person listfriends=new Person();
```

UELbook:

```
package uelbook;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class UELbook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UELbook uelbook = new UELbook();
        //test your code here
                Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Select:");
                System.out.println("[1] Add Friend");
                System.out.println("[2] Delete Friend");
                System.out.println("[3] List Friends");
                System.out.println("[4] Friends of Friends");
                System.out.println("[5] Most Popular");
                System.out.println("[6] Most Influencer");
                System.out.println("[7] Exit");
               int choice=scanner.nextInt();
               Person listfriends=new Person();
                while(choice!=7){
                 int num=0;   

                //ADD
                if(choice==1){
                System.out.println("ID: ");
                String id=scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Username: ");
                String username=scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Password: ");
                String password=scanner.nextLine();
                listfriends.set(id, username, password);
                listfriends.addFriend();
                }
                //DELETE
                if(choice==2){
                System.out.println("ID: ");
                String id=scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Username: ");
                String username=scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Password: ");
                String password=scanner.nextLine();
                listfriends.set(id, username, password);
                listfriends.removeFriend();
                }
                //LIST
                if(choice==3){
                    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
                    System.out.println(listfriends.list);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("ID: ");
                String id=scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Username: ");
                String username=scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Password: ");
                String password=scanner.nextLine();

                //REMOVE
                if(choice==7){
                System.exit(0);  
                }

                if(choice==8){
                    System.out.println("ERROR! Please choose from the options.");
                }

                }//WHILE LOOP EXIT
    }
    public void addPerson(String id, String firstname, String lastname) throws PersonExistsException {
        //list.add(ID);
               // list.add(firstname);
                //list.add(lastname);
    }
    public String getPerson(String id) throws NoSuchCodeException {
        return id; 
    }
    public void addFriendship(String id1, String id2) throws NoSuchCodeException {
            id1=id1;
            id2=id2;
    }
    public Collection<String> listFriends(String id) throws NoSuchCodeException {
        return null; 
    }
    public Collection<String> friendsOfFriends(String id) throws NoSuchCodeException {
        return null;
    }
    //The methods returns true if the file has been loaded, 
    //false in case of any errors
    public boolean loadFile(String file) {
        return false; // remove this in the implementation
    }
    //The methods returns true if the file has been saved, 
    //false in case of any errors
    public boolean saveFile(String file) {
        return false; // remove this in the implementation
    }
    public String mostPopular() {
        return null; // remove this in the implementation
    }
    public String mostInfluencer() {
        return null; // remove this in the implementation
    }
}
```

Person:

```
package UELbook;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Person {

    String ID;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[]args){

    }

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public void set(String ID, String firstname, String lastname){
        setID(ID);
        setFirstName(firstname);
        setLastName(lastname);
    }

    //SETTERS
    public void setID(String ID){
        ID=ID;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String FirstName){
       firstname=FirstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String LastName){
        lastname=LastName;
    }

    //GETTERS
    public String getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastname;
    }

     public void addPerson(String id, String firstname, String lastname) throws uelbook.PersonExistsException {
        list.add(ID);
                list.add(firstname);
                list.add(lastname);
    }   

}
```

Person Exists Exception:

```
package uelbook;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PersonExistsException extends Exception {

}
```

No Such Code Exception:

```
package uelbook;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NoSuchCodeException extends Exception {

}
```

Any helpful hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're getting an error in your IDE. Pay attention to it.

Comment: I did read it but I didn't understand it also I went and done my research on the javadocs and I still did not understand the concept of the runtime exception.

Comment: The concept is that you're using an IDE that does partial compilation, and it's letting you start your program *even though there are compile-time errors in your code* that you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Person** class is using package **UELbook**.

Presumably that should be **uelbook**.

---

(Updated to provide an explanation....)

It is only a convention (though followed 99.99% of the time) that the package name should be in all lower case. [Oracle states the following](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) as the reason for this:

> Package names are written in all lower case **to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces**.

In the code in the OP there is:

- A package named **UELbook**
- Another package named **uelbook**
- A class named **UELbook**

So you are getting a clash between class **UELbook** and package **UELbook**. Changing the package name **UELbook** to **uelbook** should fix your problem from a technical perspective. However, as a related issue, after that you should change the name of your package **uelbook** or your class **UELbook** to remove all ambiguity.

Comment: The name of the folder is UELbook and on the ide it is written as uelbook but that shouldn't make a difference should it.

Comment: I did follow you explanations however now I have an error with my class when I changed it to lower case it states " duplicate class uelbook.uelbook  "

Comment: Previously you had a name clash between package **UELBook** and class **UELBook**. Now you seem to have a name clash between package **uelbook** and class **uelbook**. As I mentioned above, _"change the name of your package uelbook or your class UELbook to remove all ambiguity"_. As in immediate fix you could just change the name of class **uelbook** to (say) **Book**. Then rebuild and verify that you have no compilation errors.